# Attach attribute [data-name] then click using this data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

I'm trying to add a data-name attribute on clicking one element and then when that element is clicked do something else.

```
$(".btn01").on("click", function() {
    $(".next").attr("data-name", "btn02");
});

$("[data-name='btn02']").on("click", function() {
    console.log("I clicked this button");
});
```

It is updating in the DOM but not working? 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use event delegation since the attribute you're using in the selector of the second click event `[data-name='btn02']` is created dynamically by the JS code:

```js
$(".btn01").on("click", function() {
  $(".next").attr("data-name", "btn02");
});

$("body").on("click", "[data-name='btn02']", function() {
  console.log("I clicked this button");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn01">CLICK ME then click the span bellow</button>
<br><br>
<span class="next">Next span</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, use event delegation for attaching event to "[data-name='btn02']", as $("[data-name='btn02']") element will not exist till $(".btn01") is clicked.

```
$(".btn01").on("click", function() {
  $(".next").attr("data-name", "btn02");
});

$(document).on("click", "[data-name='btn02']", function() {
  console.log("I clicked this button");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are just trying to make it so the first button needs to be clicked before the second can, you can just use a `boolean` variable for that:

```
var firstButtonClicked = false;
$(".btn01").on("click", function() {
    firstButtonClicked = true;    
});
// the second button
$(".next").on("click", function() {
    if (firstButtonClicked == true) {
        console.log("I clicked this button after the first one");
    }
});
```